# AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on after [5000 ms]

Tags: rest, akka, actor, akka-http

I am trying to build a money transaction system using akka-http for REST API and akka actors for AccountActors.

```
post {
  (path("accounts" / "move-money") & entity(as[MoveMoneyRequest])) { moveMoneyRequest =>

    complete(
      (bankActor ? moveMoneyRequest).map(x => MoveMoneyResponse("Money Transfer Successful!"))
    )
  }
}
```

The bankActor is created inside a main app

```
 val bankActor = mainActorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[BankingActor], accountService), name = "bankActor")
```

Inside BankActor, we have:

```
     def receive: Receive = LoggingReceive {
    case req: MoveMoneyRequest =>
      val fromAcc = createAccountActor(Some(req.fromAccount))
      val toAcc = createAccountActor(Some(req.toAccount))

      fromAcc ? DebitAccount(req.tranferAmount)
      become(awaitFrom(fromAcc, toAcc, req.tranferAmount, sender))

  }


 private def createAccountActor(accountNum: Option[String]): ActorRef = {
    actorOf(Props(classOf[AccountActor], accountNum, accountService))
  }
```

**Question:** Now, for the first API call everytime, it's successful but seems the actor dies/shuts down and the ? (ask) does not find the actor as the message does not reach the receive method. Do I need to make the ask call different?

Comment: `fromAcc ? DebitAccount(req.tranferAmount)` creates a `Future`, but it doesn't look as if you're doing anything with this `Future`. What kind of message do you expect back from the `fromAcc` actor when `BankActor` sends it a `DebitAccount` message?

Comment: Everything works and I get the expected answer **but only once** - then I have to restart the server to make the calls again & it works fine. I think the actor dies which only starts after the server is restarted....

Comment: Try replacing `fromAcc ? DebitAccount(req.tranferAmount)` with `fromAcc ! DebitAccount(req.tranferAmount)`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct directive to deal with futures is `onComplete`, for example

```
 post {
  (path("accounts" / "move-money") & entity(as[MoveMoneyRequest])) { moveMoneyRequest =>

    val fut = (bankActor ? moveMoneyRequest).map(x => MoveMoneyResponse("Money Transfer Successful!"))

    onComplete(fut){
      case util.Success(_) => complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      case util.Failure(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
    }
  }
}
```

More details in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html).

Comment: Thanks @Stefano Bonetti - I have tried this earlier but still it didn't work. The problem is it does not work on the second call. Seems the actor is disabled after the first API call!